# What code do I need for recursive programming?

Tags: python, function, recursion, sequence, computer-science

Currently I am in a discrete structures class for CS, and we are given a programming assignment in Python to study recursions. He has given us three modules, and he would like us to implement code in order to make the functions give a True or False variable. Here is his Code:

```
class WrongTypeArgumentException( Exception ): pass

def car(lst):
    """
    The first of the 3 primitive functions: return the first element of a 
    sequence. 

    .. note:: The Law of Car: The `car` function is only defined for non-empty lists.

    :param lst: a non-empty sequence; passing an empty sequence will raise an exception.
    :type lst: tuple
    :returns: an object
    :rtype: object
    """
    if type(lst) is not tuple: 
        raise WrongTypeArgumentException("Argument is not a list.")
    if len(lst)==0:
        raise WrongTypeArgumentException("List has no element") 
    if len(lst)>=1:
        return lst[0]

def cdr( lst ):
    """ The second of the 3 primitive functions: return a sequence, minus the first element.

    .. note:: The Law of Cdr: The `cdr` function is only defined for non-empty lists; the `cdr` of any non-empty list is always another list.


    :param lst: a non-empty sequence; passing an empty sequence will raise an exception.
    :type lst: tuple
    :returns: a tuple; if the sequence has only one element, return an empty sequence.
    :rtype: tuple
    """
    if type(lst) is not tuple:
        raise WrongTypeArgumentException("Argument is not a list.")
    if len(lst)==0:
        raise WrongTypeArgumentException("Cannot cdr on an empty list.")
    if len(lst)==1:
        return ()
    return lst[1:]

def cons( a, lst):
""" The third of the 3 primitive functions: return the sequence created by 
adding element `a` to the sequence `lst`.

.. note:: The Law of Cons: the primitive `cons` takes two arguments; the 
second argument to `cons` must be a list; the result is a list.

:param a: an object
:param lst: a tuple
:type a: object
:type lst: tuple
:returns: the tuple resulting from adding parameter `a` in front of sequence 
`lst`.
:rtype: tuple
"""
if type(lst) is not tuple:
    raise WrongTypeArgumentException("Argument is not a list.")
return (a,) + lst



def copy_sequence( seq ):
    """ Return the copy of a sequence, recursively.

    :param seq: the sequence to be copied
    :type seq: tuple
    :returns: a tuple, identical to the sequence that has been passed in
    :rtype: tuple
    """ 
    if seq == ():
        return ()
    print('seq={} CONSing {} to copy_sequence( {} )'.format(seq, car(seq), 
    cdr(seq)))
    return cons( car(seq), copy_sequence( cdr( seq) ))

def reverse_sequence( seq ):
    """ Return a sequence, in the reverse order, recursively.

    :param seq: the sequence to be reversed.
    :type seq: tuple
    :returns: a tuple, with the same elements, in the reverse order.
    :rtype: tuple
    """ 

    ## A function in a function (= inner function), that recursively accumulates
    ## elements in the bag
    def reverse_sequence_recursive( seq, bag):

        if seq == ():
            return bag
        return reverse_sequence_recursive( cdr(seq), cons(car(seq), bag))

    # Calling the inner function, with an empty bag to start with   
    return reverse_sequence_recursive( seq, () )
```

Here is the code that we are supposed to implement:

```
def count_sequence( seq ):
    """ Count the elements in a sequence, recursively. PROVIDE AN IMPLEMENTATION (TASK #1). This function should use **car** and **cdr**.

    :param seq: the sequence whose elements are to be counted
    :type seq: tuple
    :returns: the numbers of elements in the sequence
    :rtype: int
    """ 

def search_sequence( seq, item ):
    """ Search a sequence for the given item. PROVIDE AN IMPLEMENTATION (TASK 
    #2). This function should use **car** and **cdr**.

    :param seq: the sequence to be searched.
    :param item: the item to be searched
    :type seq: tuple
    :type item: str
    :returns: True if the item is contained in the sequence, False otherwise.
    :rtype: bool
    """ 
    ## YOUR CODE HERE #1. Base Case 2. Recursive Call 3. RC steps toward the 
    base case.  
    pass
```

And finally, here are the Test Functions he gives in order to actually test if our code is correct.

```
class PyLisp_unittest( unittest.TestCase ):
    sandwich = ("jelly","butter", "mustard", "bread", "pickles", "jam", 
    "cheese")

    def test_copy_sequence_0(self):
        """ Read empty tuple """
        sandwich = ()
        self.assertEqual( copy_sequence( sandwich ), ())

    def test_copy_sequence_1(self):
        """ Read single-element tuple"""
        sandwich = ('mustard',)
        self.assertEqual( copy_sequence( sandwich ), ('mustard',))

    def test_copy_sequence_2(self):
        """ Read 7-element tuple"""
        sandwich = ("jelly","butter", "mustard", "bread", "pickles", "jam", "cheese")
        self.assertEqual( copy_sequence( sandwich ), sandwich)


    def test_reverse_sequence_0(self):
        """ Reverse empty tuple """
        sandwich = ()
        self.assertEqual( reverse_sequence( sandwich ), ())

    def test_reverse_sequence_1(self):
        """ Reverse single-element tuple"""
        sandwich = ('mustard',)
        self.assertEqual( reverse_sequence( sandwich ), ('mustard',))

    def test_reverse_sequence_2(self):
        """ Reverse 7-element tuple"""
        sandwich = ("jelly","butter", "mustard", "bread", "pickles", "jam", "cheese")
        self.assertEqual( reverse_sequence( sandwich ), sandwich[::-1])

    def test_count_sequence_0(self):
        """ Count empty tuple """
        sandwich = ()
        self.assertEqual( count_sequence( sandwich ), 0)

    def test_count_sequence_1(self):
        """ Count single-element tuple"""
        sandwich = ('mustard',)
        self.assertEqual( count_sequence( sandwich ), 1)

    def test_count_sequence_2(self):
        """ Count 7-element tuple"""
        sandwich = ("jelly","butter", "mustard", "bread", "pickles", "jam", "cheese")
        self.assertEqual( count_sequence( sandwich ), 7)

    def test_search_sequence_0(self):
        """ Search empty tuple """
        sandwich = ()
        self.assertEqual( search_sequence( sandwich, 'ham' ), False)

    def test_search_sequence_size_1_1(self):
        """ Search  single-element tuple: successful search"""
        sandwich = ('mustard',)
        self.assertEqual( search_sequence( sandwich, 'mustard' ), True)

    def test_search_sequence_size_1_2(self):
        """ Search single-element tuple: unsuccessful search"""
        sandwich = ('mustard',)
        self.assertEqual( search_sequence( sandwich, 'ham' ), False)

    def test_search_sequence_size_7_1(self):
        """ Search 7-element tuple: successful search"""
        sandwich = ("jelly","butter", "mustard", "bread", "pickles", "jam", 
        "cheese")
        self.assertEqual( search_sequence( sandwich, 'pickles'), True)

    def test_search_sequence_size_7_2(self):
        """ Search 7-element tuple: unsuccessful search"""
        sandwich = ("jelly","butter", "mustard", "bread", "pickles", "jam", 
        "cheese")
        self.assertEqual( search_sequence( sandwich, 'pear'), False)
```

He hasn't given ANY lecture over this material, and nobody is 100 percent sure of what to do. I've tried meeting with a peer mentor, and he didn't really give much help and only rehashed the textbook definition of the sequences rather than how to implement code. So I guess I'm asking what the code would look like. What would I need to add to the `count_sequence(seq)` and the `search_sequence(seq, item)`: function. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are being asked to implement is trivial, so don't panic.

```
count_sequence(seq)
```

This is the easier of the two.  If `seq` is empty, return zero.  You'll find example tests for *empty* in the instructor's other functions, like `copy_sequence()`.

If `seq` isn't empty, then return 1 plus the result of recursively calling `count_sequence()` on the tail (`cdr()`) of `seq`.  That's it.

This can be implemented with one `if` statement that contains a `return` statement in it's body that covers one of the two cases.  The `if` statement would be followed by a `return` statement that covers the other case.

```
search_sequence(seq, item)
```

This is only slightly more code.  If `seq` is empty, return `False` this time since it's a boolean (predicate) function.  If it isn't empty, compare `item` to the first item (`car()`) of `seq`.  If they are the same, return `True`.

Otherwise, return the result of recursively calling `search_sequence()` on the same `item` but the remainder (`cdr()`) of `seq`.  The truth or falsehood of this recursive call is the answer, you don't need to examine it, just return it.

There are three cases here so this can be implemented using two `if` statements, each returning a value, and a final `return` statement that covers the third case.

Comment: you don't have to do it verbatim, but just an idea of what the code will look like.

Comment: @MacKenzyReynolds, I've added an idea of what the code might look like.  My explanations contain six times more characters than the code solutions -- they really are trivial.

Comment: okay. Thanks anyways. I thought I'd go ahead and ask then, I do get this error when I add the code in the manner you specified. 

    


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MacKenzy\Desktop\pylisp_skeleton.py", line 204, in test_count_sequence_2
    self.assertEqual( count_sequence( sandwich ), 7)
    count_sequence(cdr(seq)+1)
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Comment: @MacKenzyReynolds, I said, "1 plus the result of ... calling `count_sequence()` on the ... `cdr()` of seq".  What you did is call `count_sequence()` on the result of 1 plus the `cdr()` of seq.  *Not the same.*  You should be able to tell this is not the correct appoach as `cdr()` can return any type, so simply adding 1 can't be correct as `cdr()` may not return a number.  But `count_sequence()` always returns a number.